# github merging branch into fork before pulled into origin/master

Tags: git, github

So I have created a fork of Repo 1. My fork (Repo 1 Fork) has a branch (patch-1). I have filed a pull request to Repo 1. It is waiting to be merged.

Can I merge patch-1 into Repo 1 Fork?

Also, I want to create patch-2, is it best to create a new branch on Repo 1 Fork master?

Answer (score 0):

you can merge commit patch1 it into a fork of repo1 (lets call it fork1). as soon as patch1 is merged into repo1 and you pull from repo1 to fork1 you will get another non-fast-forward-merge (probably), but it does automerge without conflicts when you merge a commit into a branch that you already have there.

if you want to code on another feature, it is reasonable to create another feature-branch (patch2) and it is reasonable to base it on upstream master.

Answer (score 0):

Merge operations cannot be applied to repositories. They can only be applied to specific branches.

I assume that

> Can I merge `patch-1` into *Repo-1-Fork*?

means

> Can I merge my local `path-1` branch (residing in *Repo-1-Fork*) into my local `master` branch (also residing in Repo-1-Fork)?

Yes, you can. But before that, think about what suits your needs. You may want to be able to create `patch-2`, `patch-3`, etc. branches, and you may want for each of these branches to have an individual feature. If this is the case, it may be useful to not merge in order to keep your local `master` branch in sync with the *Repo-1* `master` branch.

Then if you want you can create a `developer` branch in your local *Repo-1-Fork* in which you can merge all `patch-1`, `patch-2`, etc. branches so you have a version with all the intended features.

If you merge `patch-1` into your local *Repo-1-Fork* `master` after all, then remember to create new single-feature branches from the remote *Repo-1* `master` rather than from your own. Otherwise `patch-2` will have both `patch-1` commits and the new ones that you add to it, and you won't be able to submit a single-feature pull request from `patch-2`.